# facebook remove app

Tags: php, facebook

My site has its own login system and the user can choose to connect his fb account with the site account. I wonder how the user could remove fb connection/application after being connected. I currently remove fb_id from the user table to deactivate fb connection. However, this doesn't completely remove the app from user's fb account.

Comment: You want to know how users can disconnect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Account > Privacy Settings > Apps and Websites (Edit your settings)
```

In this page you can just delete apps.

This way user can deactivate/disconnect websites/apps.

Comment: Hi, Zimbabao. I actually just want this user to disconnect with my app .

Comment: Ok. You can't force him to remove app from his a/c. It should not be a issue. You can control the access on you appside anyway.