# Facebook removed my Facebook App for social login

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-login

My Facebook Application for social login had been removed from "My Apps", and I have to **revive the original Facebook Application** because each user id would be changed in another Facebook App, or re-match the userts' data. But I have received no report/notification from Facebook, neither e-mail nor Facebook in-app.

In other questions, I noticed that [our privacy policy could be inappropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237838/facebook-remove-app), [user should be able to select options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953014/facebook-app-removed), and [a removed app caonnot undone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321078/recover-facebook-app-which-is-removed).

**Firstly, how can I know why my application had been removed?** Facebook Customer center isn't replying our case about 3 days.

**Secondly, if it cannot be undone, how could I match between the original user id and the new user id?** We have each user's data with the ID (same as Facebook-provided id), but the e-mail is not truly updated value (could be changed after registering, but not updated in our system).

Thank for all of you.

Comment: Check https://developers.facebook.com/appeal to see if your app is listed there.

Comment: @04FS Thank you for commenting, but I cannot find any listed app in that site.

Comment: So how exactly did Facebook “remove” it then? Did you get _any_ info from them about that? And what for?